# How to add parameters to this javascript/jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, param

This script allows you to click an element all you want, but when you click anything but that element, it fades something out. In my code below I can click all I want inside of `$('.wrapper')` and nothing happens, but when I click anything outside of that element, I have `$('.popup')` fadeOut.

```
(function hideElementOnOffClick(elementWrapper, elementToHide) {

    $(document).bind('click', function(evnt) {
        var $target = $(evnt.target);

       if ($target.is(elementWrapper) || elementWrapper.has(evnt.target).length) {
            return;
        }

        elementToHide.fadeOut();
    });
})();
```

then I call the function with the two element classes in it:

```
hideElementOnOffClick($('.wrapper'), $('.popup'))
```

It works find if I use `$('.wrapper')` instead of elementWrapper and `$('.popup')` instead of elementToHide, but when I make it into something I can call on in different places with different classes, it doesn't.

How do I fix the parameters so that this works?
​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.stopPropagation()` to stop event propagation, this make your code more clear.

```
function hideElementOnOffClick(elementWrapper, elementToHide) {
    elementWrapper.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        elementToHide.fadeOut();
    });    
}
```